# Calculating versors of a plane from the normal versor

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

I'm trying to calculate the 2 perpendicular versors (unit vectors), $\vec{n_1}$ and $\vec{n_2}$, that define a plane whose normal versor (unit vector) is $\vec{n_n}$.

For example, assuming that the versor of the normal is $\vec{n_n} = <1, 0, 0>$, the two perpendicular versors that define the plane whose normal is $\vec{n_n}$ should be:

- $\vec{n_1} = <0, 1, 0>$
- $\vec{n_2} = <0, 0, 1>$

Do you know an algorithm to do this job automatically?

Additional information:

- 2 points from which the $\vec{n}_n$ has been calculated;

Comment: $\vec n_1$ and $\vec n_2$ are two possible vectors in the plane, but there are infinitely many other possible choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an algorithm to find a vector that is perpendicular to your first vector $\vec{u}$  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/413235) . Starting with this couple of vectors (we will call the vector perpendicular to $\vec{u}$ as $\vec{v}$) you can simply do the cross product to find the vector that is perpendicular to both $\vec{w} = \vec{u} \times \vec{v}$ and hence obtain the couple of vectors you wanted ($\vec{v},\vec{w}$).

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

One method could be to apply the (modified) [Gram Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

To do this you would need to choose two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ not parallel to $nn$ such that $\operatorname{span}(v_1, v_2, nn) = \mathbb{R}^3$. Then set $nn$ as the first vector, $u_1$, in the Gram Schmidt process and the second and third vectors ($u_2$ and $u_3$) will be two orthogonal vectors in the plane with normal $nn$. (Here $u_i$ is referring to Wikipedia's notation for the resulting orthonormal vectors.)